# What is the Color Space of the Display Native Values on Digital Color Meter

Tags: cocoa, cgcolorspace, nscolorspace

Does anyone know what is the Color Space of the Display Native Values on Digital Color Meter and how to get this color space as a NSColorSpace or a CGColorSpace object. Thanks.
[image: DCM]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that that's `NSColorSpace.deviceRGBColorSpace` a.k.a. `NSDeviceRGBColorSpace` a.k.a. `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()`.

In other words, I think those are the actual values in the hardware framebuffer (modulo float vs. integer representation).

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. But I'm afraid this is incorrect. e.g. If you use DCM to detect a Red Color sRGB(255,0,0), the native values would be rgb(252,13,27) on DCM, however, when I convert the sRGB color to DeviceRGB color space, the result is still rgb(255,0,0).

Answer (score 1):

The "*Display native values*" color space is simply the active display profile.

[image: "Color LCD" highlighted in Digital Color Meter app user interface]

[image: selected display profile in System Preferences]

Now how do we go about getting a hold it? We have two options:

1. [`NSScreen.colorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388383-colorspace)
2. [`CGDisplayCopyColorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454190-cgdisplaycopycolorspace) — also see [`CGMainDisplayID()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455620-cgmaindisplayid)